# Shared file as persistent volume between Kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to share a persistent volume as a file between pods? For my App, I need common `/etc/hosts` among the pods.

I want to mount the hostfile placed on the NFS volume file among the pods under /etc/hosts. I cannot use statefulset here because of some limitation in statefulsets.

Comment: You shouldn't usually need to change `/etc/hosts` at all.  Does your environment have a DNS service you can use (AWS Route 53, for example), or can you use an ExternalName Service to add records to Kubernetes's internal DNS system?

Answer (score 3):

You can share it with volumes if they are mounted with an access mode as `ReadWriteMany` or `ReadOnlyMany` and [NFS supports that](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes).

But I believe a nicer approach to sharing `/etc/hosts` is just to use [`HostAliases`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/) in your pods.

Example from the K8s docs:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hostaliases-pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "127.0.0.1"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.local"
    - "bar.local"
  - ip: "10.1.2.3"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.remote"
    - "bar.remote"
  containers:
  - name: cat-hosts
    image: busybox
    command:
    - cat
    args:
    - "/etc/hosts"
```

✌️